# Emacs Indentation Problem

Tags: indentation, emacs, auctex

I started using Emacs/AUCTeX for writing my LaTeX documents. I now have an

```
\begin{inparaenum}[(1)]
  \item An Item
  \item an other Item
  \item this is an item, too !
\end{inparaenum}
```

environment. **But I can't indent** the `\item`s nor using the `TAB` Key nor by using the `indent-region` command mentioned [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Indenting.html)

Is it possible to 'auto indent' the LaTeX Code using AUCTeX.

**And how do I indent this Code?**

***EDIT:*** 
This is my `.emacs` file:

```lisp
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t) ;; .pdf statt .dvi per default:
2;;Zeilenumbruch
;; Removed to turn off 'auto-fill-mode'
;;(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
;;Syntax Higlight
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-font-lock)
;; Mathe Modus
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
;; Reftex einflechten und laden
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
;; Satzende ". " statt ". ". " f¨ur M-k: l¨oschen bis Satzende usw.
(setq sentence-end "[.?!][]\"’)}]*\\($\\| \\| \\)[
;;]*") ;; Da ist ein "Newline in der Zeile!"
(setq sentence-end-double-space nil)
;;direkte Rechtschreib Korrektur:
;;(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
;; Nur benutzen falls Auctex > 11.81 mit preview-latex:
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
;; aspell ist besser als ispell.
;; Zeile kommentieren, falls nicht installiert:
(setq-default ispell-program-name "aspell")
;; Deutsche Rechtschreibung falls \usepackage{ngerman}
;; oder german benutzt wird
(add-hook 'TeX-language-de-hook
(function (lambda () (ispell-change-dictionary "german8"))))
```

Comment: `\item`s are not intended to be indented.  If you want to indent them add `(setq LaTeX-item-indent 0)` to your `.emacs`.  That variable is mentioned in the link you provided.

Comment: @giordano that looks like an answer, rather than a comment, but worth an upvote either way ;)

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @giordano in the comments above `\item` is not indented by default. If you read carefully the [AUCTeX manual section about indenting you cited](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Indenting.html) you will see that the second paragraph explains the settings for indenting (`LaTeX-indent-level`) and the special one used for item indenting (`LaTeX-item-indent`). They have default values of `2` and `-2` respectively.

What is not made clear in the above referenced documentation is how they work together. `LaTeX-item-indent` is *extra* indentation given to `\item`s. So by default an item is indented `(+ 2 -2)` or `0`.

If you want `\item`s to be indented set `LaTeX-item-indent` appropriately according to this 'formula':

> LaTeX-indent-level + LaTeX-item-indent = desired-indent-amount

or

> LaTeX-item-indent = desired-indent-amount - LaTeX-indent-level

You can set this variable like any other with the `setq` function in Elisp.

Comment: `C-h v LaTeX-item-indent RET` gives `Extra indentation for lines beginning with an item.`  What is not clear?

Comment: The texinfo doc says "Also, items of an ‘itemize-like’ environment are indented by the value of LaTeX-item-indent, default -2." which did not make it clear to me that it is in addition to the `LaTeX-indent-level` I agree with you that the variable documentation is quite clear.